# jQuery and JS Variable to fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been playing with this code for a few hours now and can't figure it out, I have tried a number of different way to do this.

Basically, I have a few sections, with questions and radio buttons, when the next button is clicked to go to the next question, it runs my function, checks if a radio box is checked, which works if I don't use a variable, e.g ,

```
if($('input[name=question2]:checked').length > 0){
    //Do something
}
```

then fadesout one and fadesin the next question.

Where my problem is, is when I try to use a variable instead of repeating my code 5 times for each question, so when the button is pressed, it uses the variables i and j for the question numbers.

HTML

```
<section id="question2">
        <input type="radio" id="saveMoney" name="question2" value="saveMoney"/>
        <label for="saveMoney">To Help Save Money</label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" id="seeMoney" name="question2" value="seeMoney"/>
        <label for="seeMoney">Visualise My Finances</label>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin center-block" onclick="next()">Next</button>
</section>
```

JS and jQuery

```
function next(){
  var i = 2;
  var j = 3;

  if($('input[name=question "'+ i +'" ]:checked').length > 0) {
    $('#question"'+ i + '"').fadeOut();
    $('#question"'+ j + '"').delay(600).fadeIn();
    i++;
    j++;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may occur because you're using extra quotes `"` when concatenating the string and the `i` and `j` variables.

Based on your code, the first concatenation result would be `'input[name=question "2" ]:checked'` which is not the result you're looking for.

Instead of that,try with `'input[name=question'+i+']:checked'` without the extra quotes, so its outputs would be the same as when you don't use variables `'input[name=question2]:checked'`

And the same thing for the other string + variable concatenation, there are extra double-quotes `"` messing everything up.

Corrected code:

```
function next(){
    var i = 2;
    var j = 3;

    if($('input[name=question'+ i +']:checked').length > 0) {
      $('#question'+ i).fadeOut();
      $('#question'+ j).delay(600).fadeIn();
      i++;
      j++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems related to your function, in first time as explained by r1verside you are adding extra quotes. Also the counters inside the function each time is called are always resetted to 
i = 2; j = 3;

To avoid this add this variables out of the function.

```
var i = 2;
var j = 3;

function next() {
  if($('input[name=question'+i+']:checked').length > 0) {
    $('#question'+i).fadeOut();
    $('#question'+j).delay(600).fadeIn();
    i++;
    j++;
  }
}
```

an example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrh2moa2/1/

Answer (score 0):

you had some syntax mistakes with the string inside the jquery, 
no need to use the length property to see if the checkbox is checked, and the most important thing:

You need to use closures:

```
function next(){
  var i = 2;
  var j = 3;
  // this is a closure
  (function(i,j){
    // you had a typo here
    if($('input[name=question'+ i  +']:checked')) {
    $('#question'+ i).fadeOut(); 
    $('#question'+ j).delay(600).fadeIn();

 }
 })(i,j);
    i++;
    j++;
}

$("input").click(function(){next()})
```

you need to remember that the I and the J variables are initialized every time you call the function so it will work only once, a better idea would be to define I and J outside the function scope and a much better idea would be to pass them as parameters to the function.

More on closures here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help, so I have solved this problem with the help above.

Thsi is how I did it.

First off, I set the variables outside the function, because everytime a button was pressed, they where being reset, which was not what I wanted, second, with the help above, I removed the extra "" and now its working fine. Also, note for the `.length > 0`

It doesn't work without that.

Thanks again!

```
var i = 2;
var j = 3;

function test(){

   if($('input[name=question'+ i +']:checked').length > 0) {
      $('#question'+ i).fadeOut();
      $('#question'+ j).delay(600).fadeIn();
      i++;
      j++;
   } else {
  document.getElementById('warning'+ i +'').innerHTML = "Please Select an Answer";
    }
}
```